# ¿Cómo encontrar el mayor y menos valor en un arreglo de tipo double?

Tags: c#, array, double

Utilizando un arreglo llamado COMPRAS, ingresar el total de las compras efectuadas (por cada uno) de un grupo 10 trabajadores.  Buscar y mostrar en pantalla la mayor y menor compra.

Este es mi código hasta el momento:

```
using System;

namespace Ejercicio_2___Guía_de_ejercicios_de_vectores
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Declaración del arreglo que almacenará el valor total de las compras realizadas:
        double[] COMPRAS = new double[10];
        int Contador = 1; //Variable "muletilla" para facilitar el conteo
        //Ciclo de recopilación de datos:
        for (int i = 0; i<10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el valor de la compra " + Contador + " : \n");
            COMPRAS[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        }
        //Ya que se trata de un arreglo unidimensiona, podemos usar una función especial para optimizar el trabajo:
        Console.WriteLine("Valor de mayor compra realizada: " + COMPRAS.OrderByDescending(x => x).Take(1);
    }
 }
```

Sin embargo, tratándose de un arreglo con valores de tipo real, la función OrderByDescending no puede ocuparse.
¿Qué puedo hacer en ese caso entonces?

Answer (score 0):

Aconsejaria

- Cambiar el array por un `List<>`
- Usar el `First()` en lugar del `Take()`

Algo como esto

```
List<double> COMPRAS = new List<double>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Ingrese el valor de la compra {0}" : \n", i);
    double valor = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    COMPRAS.Add(valor);
}

double mayorCompra = COMPRAS.OrderByDescending(x => x).First();

Console.WriteLine("Valor de mayor compra realizada: {0}", mayorCompra);
```